# how to get merged cells of excel file only one time in c# using microsoft.office.interop.excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, office-interop, excel-interop

i am reading excel file in C# using microsoft.office.interop.excel. when the file having merged cells it is looping by containing number of cells in merged cell while i want the merged area at once

here is my method

```
public void ImportXLX()
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\Vipin\Desktop\Sheets\MyXL6.xlsx", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        int workSheetCounts = wb.Worksheets.Count;

        for (int sheetCounter = 1; sheetCounter <= workSheetCounts; sheetCounter++)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet workSheet = wb.Sheets[sheetCounter];

            Range excelRange = workSheet.UsedRange;
            Range objRange = null;

            int rowCount = 0;
            float totalRowWidth = 0;
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range row in excelRange.Rows)
            {
                rowCount++;
                totalRowWidth = row.Width;
                int colCount = 0;

                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range c in row.Cells)
                {
                    colCount++;
                    objRange = workSheet.Cells[rowCount, colCount];

                    double width = 0;
                    double height = 0;
                    string colVal = null;

                    if (objRange.MergeCells)
                    {
                        colVal = Convert.ToString(((Range)objRange.MergeArea[1, 1]).Text).Trim();
                        width = objRange.MergeArea.Width;
                        height = objRange.MergeArea.Height;


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        colVal = Convert.ToString(objRange.Text).Trim();
                        width = objRange.Width;
                        height = objRange.Height;
                    }
                    Debug.Write("objRange = " + objRange + " rowCount = " + rowCount + " Width = " + width + " height = " + height + "TotalColumnWidth = " + totalRowWidth + "TotalRowHeight = " + totalColHeight + " \n ");
                }
            }
        }
        app.Quit();
    }
```

[image]

here is the excel file screenshot

in this i want [3,1] [4,1] [5,1] [6,1] [7,1][8,1][9,1] cell just once in loop with its complete width and height

Answer (score 0):

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

You can read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0) article. You may consider using the Open XML SDK or any other third-party components designed for the server-side execution. See [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) for more information.

Comment: but i am getting merged cell i just want only cell from them

Comment: It doesn't matter what you do - this is not supported way of getting the job done.

Comment: its all done sir... thanx anyway